# Detect Reached the top of div from the bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can i detect when user scrolls to a certain div's top, from the bottom.

I tried:

```
    var pos = $("#hotspotdiv").offset();
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        if ($(window).scrollTop()>=pos.top){
          console.log("Reached DIV:");
        }
});
```

but the "Reached DIV:" is only echoed when the div is halfway on the screen.

Comment: Try using `$("#hotspotdiv").position().top`

Comment: please reproduce your issue on jsFiddle..

Answer (score 0):

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jbaeh0La/

Try the following solution:

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll===0){
        alert("Reached DIV:");
    }
});
```

Comment: I can help you more if you provide me with some HTML code or a JSFiddle